# Applying kleene star to a FSM

Tags: regex, automata

In all the examples I saw on applying Kleene star to an existing FSM ,I see that a new accepting and starting state is created and there is an epsilon transition from all accepting states into this state and an epsilon transition from the new state to the original start state. My question is why do we need a new state ? Can't we just make the original start state be an accepting state (if it not already accepting) and link to it all accepting states via epsilon transition ?

Thanks!

Gil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the original start state may have had a self-transition. Consider the language `L = a*b` with DFA

```
A -a-> A
A -b-> B
```

With `B` as the accepting state.

If you made state `A` accepting and added a transition `B -ε-> A`, the now the language accepts the word `a`. `a` is not a member of `L*`, so this new DFA is not `L*`, it's something else.

Instead, we add a new starting, accepting state `C`:

```
C -ε-> A
A -a-> A
A -b-> B
B -ε-> C
```

`a` is not a word accepted by this εNDFA anymore. This language is `L*`.